# Why my widget is not beeing rebuilded on ref.refresh?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

im new to Flutter and riverpod. What im trying to archive is a list of items fetched from server with pagination and refresh list option. Pagination works good but refresh works for some reason only when _page is > 1 otherwise widget is not beeing rebuilded.
Im trying to figure it out for few hours now. i can see that  DriverRepository().driverJobList(tab,  pages, filtering); is beeing called and that new data is appearing from json.

```
   import 'package:super_carga_mobileapp/styles.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import '../../../Driver/Jobs/model.dart';
import 'package:super_carga_mobileapp/utilis.dart';
import 'job_list_provider.dart';
import 'widgets/job_list_element.dart';


class JobListPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  List<JobListProperties> jobPropertiesList = [];
  late int _maxPages;
  int _page =1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    late ScrollController _scrollController;

    final jobListAsyncValue = ref.watch(JobListResponseProvider);

    void _loadMore() {
      if (_scrollController.position.atEdge) {
        if (_scrollController.position.extentAfter < 500) {
          if (_page < _maxPages) {
            ref.read(JobListPaginationProvider.notifier).state = ++_page;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    _scrollController = ScrollController()..addListener(_loadMore);

    Widget _buildList(int length) {
      return RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () async {
          jobPropertiesList.clear();
          if (_page > 1) {
            _page = 1;
            ref.read(JobListPaginationProvider.notifier).state = _page;
          } else {
            return await ref.refresh(JobListResponseProvider);
          }
        },
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.separated(
                controller: _scrollController,
                itemCount: length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return JobListElement(jobPropertiesList[index]);
                },
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                    const Seperator(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }



    return jobListAsyncValue.when(
      data: (data) {
        if (data.data.isNotEmpty) {
          jobPropertiesList.addAll(data.data.toList());
          final length = jobPropertiesList.length;
          _maxPages = data.pages;
          return _buildList(length);
        } else {
          return Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 60,
              ),
              Text(
                "No results",
                style: titleStyle,
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
      },
      error: (error, stackTrace) => ErrorMessage(message: error.toString()),
      loading: () {
        if (jobPropertiesList.isNotEmpty) {
          return _buildList(jobPropertiesList.length);
        } else {
          return PageLoadingSpinnerWidget();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

final JobListResponseProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose<JobListResponse>((ref) async {
  final  pages = ref.watch(JobListPaginationProvider);
  final tab = ref.watch(MiddleScreenTabProvider);
 final  filtering = ref.watch(searchTextProvider);
  return await DriverRepository().driverJobList(tab,  pages, filtering);
});

final JobListPaginationProvider = StateProvider.autoDispose<int>((ref) {
  return 1;
});

final searchTextProvider = StateProvider<Filtering>((ref) {
  return Filtering("");
});
final bottomNavIndex = StateProvider<int>((ref) {
  return 0;
});


final DeliveryButtonProvider = StateProvider<bool>((ref) {
  return false;
});
final PickupButtonProvider = StateProvider<bool>((ref) {
  return false;
});
final MiddleScreenTabProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) {
  return 1;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, now i see that my list is beeing dubled, so when _page is == 1 and i do refresh the list is beeing upended by the same values. Its not beeing cleared and then loaded with values